# How to load external CDN (seats.io) in magento 2?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, magento2

I'm trying to implement https://docs.seats.io/docs/tutorial-show-the-floor-plan-on-your-page in magento 2

I added this code in my homepage

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
        require(['jquery', 'seatsio'], function($){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                new seatsio.SeatingChart({
                    divId: 'chart',
                    publicKey: 'xxxx',
                    event: 'xxxx'
                }).render();
            });
        });
</script>
```

In requirejs-config.js I add this to load cdn :

```
paths: {
    'seatsio': 'https://cdn.seatsio.net/chart'
```

And

```
shim: {seatsio: ['jquery']}
```

In google chrome devtools the CDN is loaded but I have this error:

**Uncaught ReferenceError: seatsio is not defined**

Do you know what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `chart.js` code, the global variable `seatsio` is not set when the library is loaded via requireJS, and `require.amd` is an object.

RequireJS provides the exported value from each dependency to the module function. You can accept exported `seatsio` as second parameter as shown in following code.

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
        require(['jquery', 'seatsio'], function($, seatsio /* add this param */){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                new seatsio.SeatingChart({
                    divId: 'chart',
                    publicKey: 'xxxx',
                    event: 'xxxx'
                }).render();
            });
        });
</script>
```